# Keras: Suprising compare simple neural network 2-output and 1-output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, regression

I wrote two simple models to predict linear data. First, produce 1-output and work correctly in opposite to second which produces 2-output (but I use only first output).

```
model1 = Sequential([
    Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))
])

model2 = Sequential([
    Dense(2, input_shape=(1,))
])
```

I use standard mse in both cases.

```
def mse1(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)

def mse2(y_true, y_pred): 
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred[:,0] - y_true), axis=-1)

model1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=mse1)
model2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=mse2)

model1.fit(np.asarray(range(len(data)),dtype=np.float32), np.asarray(data), epochs=10000, batch_size=100)
model2.fit(np.asarray(range(len(data)),dtype=np.float32), np.asarray(data), epochs=10000, batch_size=100)

out1 = model1.predict(np.asarray(range(len(data))))
out2 = model2.predict(np.asarray(range(len(data))))[:,0]

plt.scatter(range(len(l)), data,  color='r')
plt.scatter(range(len(l)), out1, color='b')
plt.scatter(range(len(l)), out2, color='g') 
plt.show()
```

I try to repeat this experiment several times and always get the same result - blue (model1) work correctly but green (model2) are below most of the data points.
[image: model1 vs model2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dense layers, there is only one unit in model1, but there are two in model2. That means you have more parameter to learn in model2. Model2 is more robust than model1 in your case. But, both your models have very little parameters to learn.
You can increase the units or layers to improve the performance, but be careful the [overfitting issues](https://towardsdatascience.com/preventing-deep-neural-network-from-overfitting-953458db800a)